# Ubuntu 18.04 No Bluetooth and no WiFi suddenly

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, bluetooth

I'll start of the with the system
Dell XPS 9570, connected to a USB C thunderbolt dock.
up until yesterday, this dock was working perfectly as well, being able to pass through my external monitor etc, now it just passes power and internet.

While working yesterday, suddenly my bluetooth dropped away (my wifi also but I didn't notice because there's an ethernet cable in the dock as well). at home I got it working again after several reboots.

However today I'm sat at work, I've rebooted multiple times yet no luck. 
for both bluetooth and wif, Ubuntu decided that the hardware is gone.

I'm pretty new at using Ubuntu as a daily driver but other than SSH'ing to a different server (it's a local hosted secured server) I wasn't doing anything on my system yesterday. I'd like to figure out a more permanent solution instead of rebooting to infinity until I hopefully fix it.

stuff I tried so far:
Google, maybe my google fu is terrible but I couldn't find a related issue, most of the issues I found was at install and for me it was working fine for weeks.

Trying to get the latest drivers, no luck, I seem to be up to date.

rebooting a lot, no luck so far.

crying in a corner, heard some laugh like sounds coming from the laptop.

Any and every sarcastic/friendly/helpful/rude comment pointing me in the right direction are welcome.

Edit: it seems I've broken some more and fixed some.
The bluetooth icon has changed (I think I'm using a different controller now instead of the gnome one or something?) but is working again, so is the wifi. The dock is still no luck but with an hdmi directly to the laptop it's fine.

Edit 2: without doing anything the displayport is suddenly working again as well.

Comment: The dock is a separate device. Have you tried plugging another laptop into it, to see if this is an issue with your system or with the dock itself?

Comment: @Jos I have, I even tried a different dock with this laptop and still no luck.